# Bundle identifier and app name in iPhone & iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an app for iphone and ipad. My bundle identifier for iphone is approved but the one for ipad is rejected for the following reason:

1. iPhone app bundle identifier was eg: **com.domainname.appname**
2. iPad app bundle identifier was eg: **com.domainname.ipad.appname**

They rejected saying that the word ipad cannot be a part of the identifier. Now my problem is that I want to keep the same name for the app when the user installs the app on their device.

**My Questions:**

1. Does bundle identifier has anything to do with the name that appears when the user searches on itunes store & when they install the app?
2. If not then where does this name come from ?
3. If yes, then what should i do if I want the same app name for my iphone and ipad.

Please I am stuck to resubmit and cannot do unless I know which way to work on.

Regards, 
Shoeb

Comment: 1. No. 2. Including 'iPad' in your bundle identifier could raise conflicts with some Apple apps (both internal and external), but should generally be a unique name for each app.  Try using HD, or Plus instead of iPad.  3. You can't make two apps have the same bundle identifier, because then the system would see them as equivalent.

Comment: Simple solution man, don't use the word iPad in the name or bundle. Apple has copyrighted that name and you can't use it. Change bundle and if you are using iPad in the app name change that too. It won't get accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN NOT have the same bundle identifier for 2 apps in the Appstore. And yes Apple has the restriction, so you just replace ipad with pro or something.

And about your question if the searches depends on bundle id - definitely Not!

And you can have the same name for both the apps, but may be put it like

If you app name is App, then the ipad version can be App for iPad - it looks professional.